# Using a component defined inside another component is being loaded to DOM in Angular

Tags: angular

I have main component that has reusable component and other components that feed reusable component and any event would send back the value to the relative component. All of the above mentioned functionality works but other components are not loaded to the DOM.

maincomponent.html

```
 <app-main>
      <app-pie-chart></app-pie-chart>
 </app-main>
```

I don't see  tag in the DOM after the application is bootstrapped that is causing an issue of not appending the chart to the `<app-pie-chart>`. Is this the correct way of implementing it? I am planning to reuse app-main component for multiple charts.

Comment: Your question/code part doesn't provide enough information to understand your problem. Provide more info in detail and flow explanation.  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why not put < app-pie-chart > in your maincomponent.html? I think that bootstrapped app-main, replace all, and you "loose" your app-pie